# Restrictions on Generics list

Tags: java, generics

I have this class as an exemple :

```
public class MyClass<T extends ElementParent> {
  private Set<T> elements;   
  private Set<T> elementsNOK;

    public Set<T> getElements() {
     return elements;
    } 
 public void setElements(Set<T> elements) {
    this.elements = elements;
}

public Set<T> getelementsNOK() {
    return listeElementsNOK;
}

public void setElementsNOK(Set<T> eElementsNOK) {
    this.elementsNOK = elementsNOK;
}
```

}

After some operations on the first list (elements), i whant to add my elements to the second list (elementsNOK) :

```
for (ElementParent ele: myClass.getElements()) {
  myClass.getElementsNOK().add(ele);
}
```

How can i do this please ? it tolds me that i can add object with type ElementParent to my list.
i whant to add multiple different objects to my lists. All those objects inherited from the Class ElementParent.

Comment: Is this Java?  Please add a language tag.

Comment: What are your `getElements` and `getElementsNOK` methods? How do you create `myClass` object? Add compiler message too... Please, make question clearer.

Comment: Why did you give the `ele` variable the type `ElementParent`?

Comment: I have updated above

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the variable `myClass`, it must have been type parametrized in the declaration (assuming you are not using raw types ... which would be bad). So let's say you declared it as

```
MyClass<ElementParentSubclass> myClass = new MyClass<ElementParentSubclass>();
```

<sub>Note: In Java 7, you can use a diamond to infer the type of the left-hand side of the declaration (i.e. replace `new MyClass<ElementParentSubclass>()` with `new MyClass<>()`)</sub>

Then, to add elements from the first list to the second it would simply be

```
for (ElementParentSubclass elem : myClass.getElements()) {
    myClass.getElementsNOK().add(elem);
}
```

The reason why you could not do it your way is because the list only accepts elements of type T (which is the ElementParentSubclass type in the example above). So, although an ElementParentSubclass is an ElementParent an ElementParent is not an ElementParentSubclass.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know you Exactly the kind of my objects ElementParentSubclass (All are subClass of ElementParent )